# Comet hints using .Net

Tags: javascript, html, json, wcf, comet

I have a web site showing some data. It is constructed of:
- A web app, showing data.(ASP.Net app, but I don't use server side features in showing data; It's pure HTML and JavaScript)
- A Service providing data in Json format.(WCF)

the client requests data and receives and shows them.
Now I want to change the process in order to works in push base strategy.
I googled and I found out that that Comet is a good choice, but I don't found practical samples in my case.
Some samples had client with php (server-side) and so on.
Now I want some hints on using comet in a way that client is pure JavaScript and HTML and server is WCF (server pushes Json to JavaScript )

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27699/Scalable-COMET-Combined-with-ASP-NET-Part-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at [nComet](http://ncomet.codeplex.com/)   it is an asp.net implementation of comet, not sure if it is wcf yet, but i would have thought much of the code would be reusable.

Or better [pokein](http://www.pokein.com/Help/Documentation.aspx)